# nouveau Unknown Fermi chipset

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, graphics, 3d

I've installed a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 and whenever I start my laptop I get this output error

```
[ 19.469816] nouveau ![ DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] unknown Fermi chipset
[ 19.469846] nouveau E[ DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] unknown chipset, 0x0d7000a2
[ 19.469870] nouveau E[ DRM] failed to create 0x80000080, -22
[ 19.470095] nouveau: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -22
```

I have Lenovo G580 with nVidia Geforce 710m.

Answer (score 0):

Same laptop and same problem here. It's [a known issue in Raring](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/+bug/1142733) and it's fixed in the package `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` - version `1:1.0.8-0ubuntu1` (see comment #47 in the issue I linked). Unfortunately, the fix was included in Saucy (13.10), not in Raring ([which uses `1:1.0.7`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/1:1.0.7-0ubuntu1)). If you do upgrade to Saucy, the problem should be gone.